# How to pause & restart MongoDB cursor?

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda

I was fetching & processing a couple of millions of documents via mongoose cursor stream. It's a long running process, I want to run this into aws lambda. Is there any way I can pause the cursor, persist the state & restart it later?

Comment: If it's a long running operation, I don't think Lambda is the best solution. It was designed for intermittent load with little resources. Inserting a new document might work well with Lambda, but using it for batch processing is stretching its usability.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the server will automatically close the cursor after 10 minutes of inactivity, or if client has exhausted the cursor. To override this behavior from the driver, you can use [addCursorFlag](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#addCursorFlag) with `noCursorTimeout` option:

```
collection.find({}).addCursorFlag('noCursorTimeout', true)     // Set cursor as noCursorTimeout
```

After setting the noCursorTimeout option, you must either close the cursor manually or by exhausting the cursor’s results.

Comment: One caveat is if your application crashes, or was forcibly stopped by Lambda, this cursor will live forever in the server, similar to a memory leak. The only way to recover is to restart the server. This is one reason why it's not usually recommended to have a notimeout cursor. Rather, it's usually better to set a really high timeout value instead.